# PowerBI report, values from decimal to percentage

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am a complete newbie in PowerBI, I have a PowerBI report and my first task is to take values "expected seat load factor" and turn them into percentage. so in the example I just showed, it would be 79% . I have the current panel and I don't know where to start.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the measure or column in the data panel and then select percentage from the ribbon.

[image]